# set up custom localhost directory in apache2 using Debian

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, localhost, debian

apologize that I am quite new with this virtualbox thing. 
I am using Oracle Virtualbox and I am with Debian system.

I have installed php, apache and mysql on the debian system now.

I want to test my site in a directory that I created. I want to be able to access 'localhost/phpmyadmin/' from the browser just like the way I did with wamp in my windows system normally.

Now when I go to localhost, I can see the text: 'it works!...'

Where is this web file in my virtual machine exactly?

More importantly, I can't figure out how to specify the right custom directory in userdir.conf module. I tried to gedit the userdif.conf and php5.conf files. I got a warning:
Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.TX1V0W':No such file or directory

and several similar warnings

Here is my userdir.conf code now:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

and the php5.conf file is like this:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_value engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

It doesn't work apparently, I still can't get phpmyadmin. What shall I do now?

Answer (score 0):

there are several issues here:

### virtualbox

there is absolutely nothing in your problem that is related to virtualization.

apache has `VirtualHost`s, which allows one apache webserver have different configurations for multiple domains (e.g. `http://mysite.com` and `http://widerwachs.org` might be served by the same apache instance, but are otherwise completely different. you would then configure one VirtualHosts for each domain).

the naming might be confusing, but apache's `VirtualHost` predates any reasonable hardware virtualization.

### userdir

`userdir` is really for per-user websites, that is `http://localhost/~foo/` and `http://localhost/~bar/` for the users `foo` resp. `bar`.

any "normal" website (e.g. `http://localhost/sudel`) has usually nothing to do with `userdir`.

so it is most likely not what you are looking for. (at least it has nothing to do with the rest of your problem)

### website root

the filesystem root of your website can be set with the `DocumentRoot` directive.
on debian system, it usually defaults to `/var/www`

### alias

you most likely will not find anything `phpmyadmin` related in `/var/www`.
you probably should NOT.
instead, you should read the documentation that comes with the `phpmyadmin` package, esp. the `README.Debian`.

you will find that you should add a line like `Alias /phpmyadmin /foo/bar/baz` to your apache config, which will make `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` look for files into `/foo/bar`/baz` on your filesystem.

however, this is most likely done by creating a symlink from `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf` to `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` (untested)

### file editing

it seems that you are running X as `root` user (aka `superuser`). you probably should not do this for security reasons. instead try to learn a reasonable text editor that works on the cmdline.

### stackoverflow

[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is really about programming questions. you should ask system-administrator questions on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).